# How do I execute a php-cli from php-cgi with nohup

Tags: php

I am trying to execute a php-cli script from php-cgi
What I got below does not work from cgi.
It does however work when I execute it directly from a shell.
Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
<?php 

if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli')
{
    require '../boot.php';
    Logger::mailit();
    exit;
}

class Logger {

    private static $instance = NULL;

    private function __construct(){}

    public function __destruct()
    {
        if (PHP_SAPI != 'cli')
        {
            exec('nohup php '. __FILE__ .' &');
        }
    }


    public static function mailit(){

        // Database stuff ...

        mail( $row->email, $row->subject, $row->message, $row->headers);
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it actually working, and it was all just a little bug

changed this:

```
require '../boot.php';
```

to this:

```
require __dir__.'/../boot.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to place the call (`Logger::mailit()`) of your class after the definition (`class Logger`) of your class.

Answer (score -1):

You can either remove the CLI check `if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli')`, or include the file and call  `require '../boot.php'; Logger::mailit();` yourself. Or you can look into [exec()](http://php.net/exec) (or [proc_open()](http://php.net/proc_open), …) to execute the script as its own process. This might be necessary if you need the sandboxing.

---

have you tried something like `exec('your/script.php &')`? ([NOHUP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup))

---

with [proc_open()](http://php.net/proc_open) you can setup the environment for your script (including funky file descriptor stuff). with [proc_get_status()](http://php.net/proc_get_status) you can get the PID of the process you started with proc_open(). With [posix_kill()](http://php.net/posix_kill) you can send signals to a process.

If I'm not mistaking, your parent process (in your case the php-cgi) keeps running until the child process (in your case the php-cli) finished - even if you setup non-blocking execution.